# How can I tell jsonpickle which class to create when deserializing json that does not have jsonpickle metadata/type information

Tags: python, json

I'm new to python but in other languages I have been able to tell a serializer what type I want created and let it deserialize or bind the properties based on reflection/introspection.

jsonpickle adds type information to the json if you serialize it with jsonpickle, however in this case the json I am getting comes from an external source and does not have the type metadata in it.

I would like to just pass the type information to a serializer.

```
import jsonpickle

class TestObject(object):

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        self._name = value

#from an external source
jsons = '{ "name" : "Test" }'
```

I would expect I could just do something like:

```
jsonpickle.decode(jsons,TestObject)
```

Here is a C# example of my question:
http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject_3.htm

The c# would look like:

```
public class TestObject {
    public string Name { get;set; }
}

var json = "{ "name" : "Test" }";

var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json,typeof(TestObject));
```

I know python is not typed, etc ... but there is no reason why I should need to be messing around with dictionary maps just to do basic serialization.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Have you read the [`jsonpickle` docs](http://jsonpickle.github.io/)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think my question is fairly simple. I have read the docs and the source. I'll attempt to update the question

Answer (score 1):

First of all the example json output you provided is not what jsonpickle will output. Instead an encoded instance of the TestObject you defined would look like this:

```
'{"py/object": "__main__.TestObject", "_name": 4}'
```

Note that the type is encoded along with the instance variables. The decoded output will magically be put back into its original type:

```
jsonpickle.decode('{"py/object": "__main__.TestObject", "_name": 4}')
```

will be a TestObject instance.

Comment: I know jsonpickle will add the type information, but the json in this case does not come from jsonpickle. I would just like to pass the type as a parameter since it is not in the json.

Comment: In that case you are simply asking how to instantiate the class given a json key-value map. First I would recommend converting the json to a python dictionary, you can use jsonpickle or just json for this. Second I would iterate through the .items() in the dictionary and call setattr(obj,key,value). Unfortunately jsonpickle doesn't have a builtin method for doing this already, but maybe another library does.

Comment: that's a lot of work. the json in my question is trivial for example sake. I don't want to write a serializer and deal with all the nested objects, etc that may be in the json. I guess what I'm getting from the answers and downvotes is that python doesn't appear to have a library that does this. In java/c# etc ... which is more difficult to deserialize (given the type information) ... these libraries are very common and this deserialization process is the norm.

Comment: Question now states "the json I am getting comes from an external source".  I realize this question is 7 years old, but you might clean up this answer a bit.  This use case is very common, and the question is still getting views.