# How to deserialise Json in Python that doesn't have special type information etc

Tags: python, json

How can I deserialise json from an external source in Python?
Jsonpickle looks like a likely candidate, but I've only been able to get it to work with json it's created (which has special type information). Is there something I've missed in this libary, is there another libary?

A while ago as similar but not identical question was asked [How can I tell jsonpickle which class to create when deserializing json that does not have jsonpickle metadata/type information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25108056/how-can-i-tell-jsonpickle-which-class-to-create-when-deserializing-json-that-doe/25108462#25108462).
For the avoidance of confusion, here is an example of the sort of thing I mean, written in Go. The jsonSrc is from an external source and cannot be changed.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type MyJsonName struct {
    Name                string `json:"name"`
    UpcomingEventsCount int    `json:"number_of_angsty_songs"`
}


func main() {
    jsonSrc := []byte(`{"name":"Weezer","number_of_angsty_songs":99}`)

    var myJson MyJsonName
    json.Unmarshal(jsonSrc, &myJson)

    fmt.Println(myJson.Name)
}
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: I think you could use the `object_hook` argument of `json.loads`

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here `jsonSrc` is a perfectly normal JSON string, and can be processed by the standard json libraries in all languages including Python.

Comment: are you able to include your python code?